# ANSI commands for drawing boxes in terminal

Tags: terminal, draw, ansi-escape, line-drawing

I am trying to draw a box on the screen that looks like this:

```
┌───┐



└───┘
```

I found ANSI commands to move the cursor here:

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html

My code looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    int boxsize = 5;
    std::string bs = std::to_string(boxsize);
    std::string up = "\033[<"+bs+">A";
    std::string down = "\033[<"+bs+">B";
    std::string back = "\033[<"+bs+">D";

    std::cout << "┌";
    for (int i = 0; i < boxsize-2; ++i)
    {
    std::cout << "─";
    std::cout << down;
    std::cout << "─";
    std::cout << up;
    }
    std::cout << "┐";
    std::cout << down;
    std::cout << "┘";
    std::cout << back;
    std::cout << "└";
}
```

And my result is this:

```
┌─5>B─5>A─5>B─5>A─5>B─5>A┐5>B┘5>D└
```

Am I using the ANSI commands incorrectly or is this an issue with my terminal (yakuake)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle brackets (`<` and `>`) in these lines should be removed:

```
std::string up = "\033[<"+bs+">A";
std::string down = "\033[<"+bs+">B";
std::string back = "\033[<"+bs+">D";
```

In the [TLDP](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html) page, `<N>` is supposed to be a number, using an archaic notation to denote italicized text, e.g., *N*.

Even with that, you still have work to do, but this is a start:

```
┌─ ─ ─ ┐




  ─ └ ─ ┘
```